# Ubuntu 15.10 Maximizing to wrong screen

Tags: unity, nvidia, 15.10, multiple-monitors, compiz

This is my first post here. I just upgraded (well, reinstalled) to Ubuntu 15.10. I'm using the closed source nvidia driver with 2 video cards and 4 monitors (2 per card).

I'm Using X-screen0 for the 'normal' unity/compiz desktop and I'm running vmware in full-screen mode on X-screen1 with openbox as a window manager.

The problem is on X-screen0, running unity/compiz.
Whenever I maximize a windows on my left monitor, the window will get maximized on the right monitor.
A second, maybe unrelated, issue is when some window is active, and I click within a browser on the left monitor, that window will move to the right, slightly into my right monitor.

When I disable my 2 monitors on X-screen1 i can get things to work only when I set my right monitor as primary in nvidia-settings, otherwise windows will maximize spanning both monitors.

This is my xorg.conf:
    # nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
    # nvidia-settings:  version 352.21  (buildd@lgw01-37)  Thu Jul 23 11:50:49 UTC 2015

```
Section "ServerLayout"

# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
Screen      1  "Screen1" 3471 0
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

# generated from default
Identifier     "Mouse0"
Driver         "mouse"
Option         "Protocol" "auto"
Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

# generated from default
Identifier     "Keyboard0"
Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Idek Iiyama PLE2200"
HorizSync       30.0 - 84.0
VertRefresh     55.0 - 77.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier     "Monitor1"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "DELL 1907FP"
HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GT 620"
Option         "RANDR" "Enable"
BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device1"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "Quadro FX 570"
BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "RANDR" "Enable"
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +1680+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen1"
Device         "Device1"
Monitor        "Monitor1"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "RANDR" "Enable"
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DVI-I-3: nvidia-auto-select +1280+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"

# Option "Composite" "Enable"
Option         "RANDR" "Enable"
EndSection
```

And the graphics cards:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 620] (rev a1)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G84GL [Quadro FX 570] (rev a1)
```

uname:

```
$ uname -a
Linux chef 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried using the 'put' compiz plugin, and using a "put to adjacent viewport" shortcut, but this has no effect (i.e. pressing the shortcut does nothing).

I'd like to watch some youtube crap on my left monitor while working on the others :)

Let me know if you need more info about my setup.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apparently my problem has been magically solved.

I apt-get'ted plasma-desktop and tried that, just to see if that would allow me to maximize windows on both monitors. Nope. I could not even drag windows to my left monitor. It would split-screen maximize the window on the right monitor instead.
Not feeling like fiddling with an unfamiliar desktop environment for too long, I purged it. After which, back in my unity desktop, things magically worked! I can maximize windows on both monitors. Watch videos full screen on either monitor and the strange moving/jumping of a window when giving it focus on my left monitor has disappeared as well.

I have no clue why things are working now, but they are. :)